# Error when trying to run executeJavascript()

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Hello I would like to be able to insert the result of a function written in python that I get in the variable data but when I tried to insert the value of this variable, the command `document.getElementById("h1-fs-s5").innerHTML` does not execute with the value of data when trying to concatenate and an error appears.

Here is a part of the code:

```
subpy.stdout.on('data',function(data){
          console.log("data: ",data.toString('utf8'));
            mainWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript(` document.getElementById("h1-fs-s5").innerHTML = "${data.toString('utf8')}" ; `);
          });
```

Here is the error that i have :

```
(node:2208) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Script failed to execute, this normally means an error was thrown. Check the renderer console for the error.
    at WebFrame.<computed> (C:\Users\cantr\Desktop\Stage ing├®nieur KOMILFO SPORT\Sail Vision\Dashboard\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\electron.asar\renderer\api\web-frame.js:64:33)
    at WebFrame.executeJavaScript (C:\Users\cantr\Desktop\Stage ing├®nieur KOMILFO SPORT\Sail Vision\Dashboard\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\electron.asar\common\api\deprecate.js:114:32)
    at C:\Users\cantr\Desktop\Stage ing├®nieur KOMILFO SPORT\Sail Vision\Dashboard\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\electron.asar\renderer\web-frame-init.js:11:43
    at C:\Users\cantr\Desktop\Stage ing├®nieur KOMILFO SPORT\Sail Vision\Dashboard\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\electron.asar\renderer\ipc-renderer-internal-utils.js:7:40
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\cantr\Desktop\Stage ing├®nieur KOMILFO SPORT\Sail Vision\Dashboard\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\electron.asar\renderer\ipc-renderer-internal-utils.js:7:9)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:200:13)
    at Object.onMessage (C:\Users\cantr\Desktop\Stage ing├®nieur KOMILFO SPORT\Sail Vision\Dashboard\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\electron.asar\renderer\init.js:42:16)
(node:2208) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Script failed to execute, this normally means an error was thrown. Check the renderer console for the error.
    at WebFrame.<computed> (C:\Users\cantr\Desktop\Stage ing├®nieur KOMILFO SPORT\Sail Vision\Dashboard\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\electron.asar\renderer\api\web-frame.js:64:33)
    at WebFrame.executeJavaScript (C:\Users\cantr\Desktop\Stage ing├®nieur KOMILFO SPORT\Sail Vision\Dashboard\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\electron.asar\common\api\deprecate.js:114:32)
    at C:\Users\cantr\Desktop\Stage ing├®nieur KOMILFO SPORT\Sail Vision\Dashboard\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\electron.asar\renderer\web-frame-init.js:11:43
    at C:\Users\cantr\Desktop\Stage ing├®nieur KOMILFO SPORT\Sail Vision\Dashboard\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\electron.asar\renderer\ipc-renderer-internal-utils.js:7:40
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\cantr\Desktop\Stage ing├®nieur KOMILFO SPORT\Sail Vision\Dashboard\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\electron.asar\renderer\ipc-renderer-internal-utils.js:7:9)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:200:13)
    at Object.onMessage (C:\Users\cantr\Desktop\Stage ing├®nieur KOMILFO SPORT\Sail Vision\Dashboard\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\electron.asar\renderer\init.js:42:16)  
(node:2208) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:2208) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:2208) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process 
with a non-zero exit code.
(node:2208) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process 
with a non-zero exit code.
```

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the data type returned by the python program, so I converted data via the `parseInt(data)` function to make it work and not with `toString('utf8')`.